# Maximum number of pairwise externally tangent congruent cylinders in space

Tags: geometry

What is the maximum number of congruent cylinders (radius $r$, height $h$, for your choice of $r,h$) that can be arranged in space so that each cylinder touches every other cylinder?

I'm aware of an arrangement of 7, and I'm unsure if there is a proof of impossibility for 8.

Comment: Are your cylinders of finite length? And if so, can they be "tangential" if the end of one butts up against another, like a 'T' shape?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a classic puzzle (Martin Gardner) to do this with 7 cylinders, depending on $r$ and $h$, and it seems to have been recently discovered that you can do so even when the cylinders are infinitely long: here's an [article](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/guest-blog/2014/04/01/magic-puzzles-delight-math-fans-at-g4g/) on the 11th "Gathering for Gardner" from earlier this year.

As far as I know, the eight-cylinder problem is still open, whether finite or infinite. The article writes, "It might even be possible to achieve the same feat with eight infinite [cylinders]."

Comment: Thanks for the link! Very cool stuff.

Comment: @David You're welcome! You might also be interested in an article by András Bezdek, *[On the Number of Mutually Touching Cylinders](http://library.msri.org/books/Book52/files/07bezd.pdf)*, in which he shows that the upper bound is $24$. The article was written about ten years ago, so the solution for $7$ infinite cylinders hadn't been found yet. Someone may have also found a better upper bound since then.